# MustOverride turns out as a Virtual Method?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, overriding, .net-assembly, abstract-methods

While researching **Assembly.GetInterfaces()**, I found the method was a **MustOverride method**. Which in my understanding means it has no default action to derived classes. Its just a signature basically, an abstract method. Yet, I can still use it on a type and it will return all implemented interfaces without writing any code for the MustOverride method.

Where is this code that has slipped into the MustOverride method? Have I somehow indirectly overridden it just simply by calling the method on a created type?

This question is purely on the basis of study and discovery, I am not trying to do anything other than understand the confines of the language.

Here is the code I used:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim t As Type

        Debug.WriteLine(GetType(Integer))
        t = GetType(Integer)
        Dim interfaceArr As Type() = t.GetInterfaces

        For i As Integer = 0 To interfaceArr.Length - 1
            Debug.WriteLine(interfaceArr(i))
        Next

    End Sub

End Class


Output Is:

System.IComparable
System.IFormattable
System.IConvertible
System.IComparable 1[System.Int32]
System.IEquatable 1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: This question describes MustOverride in a bit more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1686872/1157215

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can still use it on a type and it will return all implemented interfaces".  Can you provide more details or an example of what you mean?

Comment: Thanks.  And what output are you seeing which you didn't expect to see?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see any output on a MustOverride method that I did not add any code to. Are these methods not void of function until code is added?

Comment: What MustOverride method are you seeing?  The output is merely showing interfaces, not methods.

Comment: The t.GetInterfaces is a mustOverride Method  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `MustOverride` method can always be called on an instance of any type because you couldn't possibly create an instance of a class unless the class provides concrete implementations of all of the `MustOverride` methods.  In this case, your confusion is that you are assuming that the `t` variable is referencing a `Type` object, but that is not the case.  Since `Type` is a `MustInherit` class, it's impossible to ever instantiate an object of that type directly.  You could only ever instantiate an object of a class that *derives* from `Type`.  If you use the debugger to inspect the `T` variable, you will notice that it is actually referencing an instance of the `RuntimeType` class, which is an undocumented class which obviously derives from `Type`.

For instance, consider this example, which duplicates the behavior:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
        Public MustOverride Function GetGreeting() As String
    End Class

    Public Class DerivedClass
        Inherits BaseClass

        Public Overrides Function GetGreeting() As String
            Return "Hello world"
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Function GetInstance() As BaseClass
        Return New DerivedClass()
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim t As BaseClass = GetInstance()
        Debug.WriteLine(t.GetGreeting())
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, the `t` variable is of the `BaseClass` type, but it's actually referencing a `DerivedClass` object.  Therefore, even though the `BaseClass` class defines the method as `MustOverride`, you can still call it because the actual type of the object does implement it.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. Does this make you suspect that the code for those MustOverride methods, is being provided "behind the scenes" as soon as the RuntimeType, or any derived class is created automatically?

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "behind the scenes", and I certainly wouldn't say it's "automatic".  The `RuntimeType` is a real class in the .NET Framework, just like any other class.  It derives from the base `Type` class.  In the `RuntimeType` class, all `MustOverride` methods are being overridden and their implementation is being specified.  If they were not, there would be no way for the `GetType` function to create an instance of the `RuntimeType` class.  I will update my answer with an example that duplicates the behavior.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I suppose its Delegation that I need to brush up on.